# Select datas from two separate tables for a news feed in MySQL/PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, feed

I would like to select datas from two separate tables to make a newsfeed like facebook which would display both photos, news or reviews (or anything) in one list and ordered by their date. Right now, I have two lists on my website which show photos and news separately. I'd like to have just one list which would contain all the items.

Here's a example:

```
news 1  : june 20
photo 1 : june 15
photo 2 : june 13
news 2  : june 12
photo 3 : june 9 
review 1: june 5
```

I tried this SQL query:

```
SELECT n.id, n.title, n.date, t.id_photo, t.url, t.date_photo 
FROM news AS n, photos AS t 
ORDER BY n.date DESC, t.date_photo DESC 
LIMIT 0,30
```

But this didn't work. Any idea?

NB: There's no link between those tables. There're completely different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
<?php
    $newsPage = isset($_GET['newspage']) ? $_GET['newspage'] : 0;
    $photosPage = isset($_GET['photospage']) ? $_GET['photospage'] : 0;
    $selectNews = mysqli_query("SELECT `news`.`id`, `news`.`title`, `news`.`date`
                                FROM `news`
                                ORDER BY `news`.`date` DESC
                                LIMIT ".$newsPage."0,10;");
    while($news = mysqli_fetch_assoc($selectNews)) {
        echo $news['title'].'<br />';
    }
    $selectPhotos = mysqli_query("SELECT `photos`.`id_photo`, `photos`.`url`, `photos`.`date_photo` 
                                FROM `photos`
                                ORDER BY `photos`.`date_photo` DESC
                                LIMIT ".$photosPage."0,10;");
    while($photos = mysqli_fetch_assoc($selectPhotos)) {
        echo '<img src="'.$photos['url'].'" alt="Image" title="Image" /><br />';
    }
```

Lemme know how it goes.

Comment: Your LEFT JOIN shouldn't be on a table ?

Comment: You're right, sorry. Updated the main reply and tested it, it works.

Comment: Thank you. It worked, I thought it would be more complicated and should have tried something like that for the beginning :p.

Comment: Didn't work finally :/. With your code, we join photos and news if they have the same ID. But if I have a phot with ID 1000 and there's no news with this ID, the photo won't be displayed.

Comment: Try joining with the dates? Which parts of the tables are the same?

Comment: There is no part of the table which is the same. I would just like to display them in a single list. But there's no link between the two tables. I chose photos for example but I could have chose to list news about politics and reviews about movies which are in two separate tables.

Comment: For this, then if there is no link between the tables, you should use two select queries. I have updated the main answer with the queries you need.

Comment: I know how to do two queries but I'm displaying only 30 informations because I use a Pagination. So how would you do that ? How could I know how much news I have to select and how much photos so I can assemblate the two queries then and order them.

Comment: I have written the code out for you, that should work using $_GET pages.

Comment: You didn't get what I want to do :p ! I'm very familiar with PHP and I know all about that :p. What I want to do is displaying news AND photos in a single list ordered by dates. So if I have a news which is more older than a photo, the photo appears first. And if there's a photo more older than the news, it would display : photo - news - photo. Do you get it?

Comment: Ok yeah, I get it now, for that, the way I would do it is.. I would create another table called `newsandphotos` containing the columns `id`, `type`, `date`. `Id` would contain the item id, type would contain the item type (1 for `news`, 2 for `photo`) and then `date`, the date posted. And then get the data using php from that.

Comment: Ok I tbhought there could be a way for doing this by a signle request but that was my second option :). Thanks for the help, +1 for this ;) !